# My django tests are not working due to order of south's schema migrations?

Tags: python, django

When I run

```
manage.py test myapp
```

it dies with this error

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 
   'test_dom.#sql-49b_1a1' (errno: 150)")
```

I am using `south` to handle schema migrations, django 1.3 and mysql.

Note that when I configure the project individually, I do the following in order

- syncdb
- migrate app1
- migrate app2
- migrate

The last migration applies to all the other apps. If I don't do the migration manually for the first 2 apps; south will crash on me as well.

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do a migrate after a syncdb? Surely you have no migration to do after a freshly created db?

Also note the south settings:

SKIP_SOUTH_TESTS = True
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False

Comment: Migrating after a syncdb is a valid use case http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#the-first-migration

Answer (score 3):

do you know that you can define dependencies in south migrations?

http://south.aeracode.org/docs/dependencies.html

If you define the dependencies, a single "manage.py migrate" should work. If not, please post the error message.